# phpMyAdmin - 403 permission denied - Centos7

Tags: apache-2.4, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin on my server running apache 2.4.6 on Centos7, I am getting error as You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

my server ip is `62.210.xx.xx`
I am browsing `62.210.xx.xx/phpmyadmin/` remotely from another ip `xx.xx.xx.xx`

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf**

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip 62.210.xx.xx
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     #Order Deny,Allow
     #Allow from 127.0.0.1
     #Allow from ::1
     #Allow from 62.210.xx.xx
     #Deny from All
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/">
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip 62.210.xx.xx
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from 62.210.xx.xx
     #Deny from All
     #Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/">
    #Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    #Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/">
    #Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    #Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/">
    #Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from All
    #Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
#        #SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I have added line `Require ip 62.210.xx.xx`  and `Allow from 62.210.xx.xx` as suggested in other questions here but still its not working.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks

update its working with `Require all granted` and `Require mylocalIP` but that's not I want I want to allow from my server ip `62.210.xx.xx` or local ip range only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to make it work following [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_host.html) official document, as I am browsing from local ip I need to tell apache my local ip range.

added `Require ip xxx.xx` where `xxx.xx` are my local partial IP address for dial up connection, if you have dedicated ip add full ip `Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

And now its working.

I hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to look at the main apache config to see any restrictions in there for access to directories. The config to look for would be:

Order deny,allow
Deny fromall

Order allow,deny
allow from all

If this does not work, then check permissions on the file system. If this does not work, is the phpadmin a symlink to somewhere else that is not covered under:

Order deny,allow
Deny fromall

Order allow,deny
allow from all

HTH
Kobus

Comment: I guess I need to add my local IP range in `Require ip`.

Comment: You can, but i dont think is is required if the server is not externally available.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I installed PHPMyAdmin in my CentOS 7 VPS. I have fixed the issue by adding this line **Require all granted** in the directory section. Below is an example.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Note: Replace the IP address with 127.0.0.1